# i have a custom structural directive that using a promise in the ngOnInit to get an auth state from an API that doesn't refresh when i login or logout

Tags: angular, authentication, promise, directive, angular-changedetection

I have a custom structural directive that using a promise in the ngOnInit to get an auth state from an API , that directive show or delete element based on an auth state that it gets from an API,

it works fine but when i login the directive is still on the old state and you should refresh the page so the directive update ,in the ngDocheck of the directive it knows that an event has been fired (login/logout buttons) but i don't want it to send request on every change detection cycle, how could i custom the change detection to work on this scenario. "I know i could use observable subject to solve this, I want to try other solutions".

1. [before logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJr9.png) ||
2. [after logging in and before refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KavAj.png) ||
3. [after logging in and after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3yOY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the ngOnChanges function could help you !
try to learn more about it https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Comment: ngOnChanges work when input changes, my directive has no inputs it uses a promise inside ngOnInit, maybe somthing like event emitter that tells the directive to  recall the promise could help